# Prevent initial form from "refreshing" when subform is run

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following (refined) code:

**Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    GetIP getIP;
    string deviceIP = "";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (deviceIP == "") 
        {
            getIP = new GetIP();
            var result = getIP.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string ip = getIP.IPAddress;
                deviceIP = ip;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        form2 = new Form2();
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**GetIP**

```
public partial class GetIP : Form
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }
    public GetIP()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPAddress = txtIPAddress.Text;
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }
}
```

**Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(); // oops...this might be it?

    public Form2(string deviceData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Force CRLF (\r\n) on all newline instances
        deviceData = deviceData.Replace("\r\n", "\n");
        deviceData = deviceData.Replace("\r", "\n"); 
        deviceData = deviceData.Replace("\n", "\r\n");
        txtdeviceData.Text = deviceData;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Close();
    }
}
```

My issue is, whenever `Form2` attempts to open, `Form1` seems to refresh.  This causes `GetIP` to run again (which also means that `deviceIP` was reinitialized back to "").  `Form2` does not open until after `GetIP` is completed.

The check for `deviceIP == ""` was my attempt at solving the problem, but it seems that the variable initialization is also re-run, thus nullifying my check.

Is there a way to prevent `Form1` from refreshing, or at least a way to prevent `GetIP` specifically from being run again?

*Update*
Hmm, I just noticed I have what seems to be a leftover line of code which creates a `Form1` instance...

Comment: Why don't you pass the IP on the constructor of form2?

Comment: `Form2` has no operations which require the IP.  `Form2` does actually get data passed to it, but I have left it out for simplicity.

Comment: We would have to see your Form2 code.  This `if (deviceIP == "")` line shouldn't be needed.  It will never be false during the constructor.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for requesting the `Form2` code.  I wasn't sure what it would accomplish at first, but it led me to detect what seems to be the cause :P

Yep, that was it...thanks!!

Comment: That line that says `oops this might be it` would not affect your original instance of `Form1`, since `deviceIP` is not a static field.

Comment: @RufusL But it is causing it to run again, is it not?  After removing `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`, the problem is now gone.  I have also removed the `if (deviceIP == "")` condition.

Comment: I don't see how that would make a difference since it's a local instance to `Form2` and the fields aren't `static`, but if removing that line fixed it, then I guess you found the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1 = new Form1(); // oops...this might be it?
```

Yes, that "oops" is it.

If Form2 needs to have a reference to Form1, try passing it through the constructor:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  Form1 form1 = null;

  public Form2(Form1 f1, string deviceData) {
    InitializeComponent();
    form1 = f1;
    // etc, etc.
  }
```